# OpenGL face culling when scaling Y with -1

Tags: opengl

I have a simple stair (vertices in an array):

```
[]
[][]
```

I want this stair upside-down:

```
[][]
[]
```

To get this shape, I multiply each Y-Coordinate with `-1`, so basically scaling with `-1` around the `y-axis`. This works great, but not with face culling, when face culling is enabled, the back-faces are shown. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can flip the direction of face culling when you draw these inverted objects.

Just call `glFrontFace()` with GL_CW or GL_CCW, and put it back when you draw normal objects again.

Comment: Unfortunatly that's impossible, I am writing the vertices into a VBO and drawing them together with others.

Comment: @dav1d: That doesn't explain why you can't just render this one object with an inverted face culling. After all, you have to give it a special matrix that negates the Y, right? Also, if that is an issue, you should put it into the *question*.

Comment: If you're putting it into a VBO like this, can't you just reverse the winding of your triangles in the VBO? When you mirror the vertices, it flips the winding. You can either tell OpenGL to use a different winding, flip it yourself, or disable culling. There's really no other option. @dav1d

Comment: @NicolBolas, I don't understand it, you mean I should negate Y again in the shader? I'll try to change the winding, this sounds promising.

Comment: @dav1d: If you aren't negating the Y in the shader, where *are* you negating it?

Comment: @NicolBolas when generating the vertices (before writing them into the buffer). You can see the "normal" stair, as "template stair" for the upside-down. It's a simple: `vertex[1] *= -1` where `vertex` is `float[3]`.

Answer (score 2):

You could reverse the side of the front faces ([glFrontFace](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFrontFace.xml)), or you can disable the backface culling.

Comment: I don't want to disable backface-culling (it has a too huge impact on the performance). Do you have an example how to reverse them? I can't think of something.